# How to deal with self-signed certificate in the Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, google-chrome-app, self-signed

I'm developing a Chrome App, which connects to the server over SSL. Of course, the certificate is self-signed.

In the Chrome browser, it's not a problem because Chrome opens a security warning page. If user chooses to continue to the website, it goes on to the remote page. However, in the Chrome Apps, it doesn't give such a warning page asking user whether to go on or not. Instead, a connection error is thrown out in the console.

To workaround this problem, the user has to connect to the page in the browser once and accepts the certificate, and then he/she could proceed in the Chrome Apps.

I'm wondering how to deal with this issue in the Chrome Apps directly?

Comment: Why "of course"? A real SSL cert costs less than domain registration these days.

Comment: Well, the issue is a lot of our customers still use self-signed certificate. It's not decided by me.

Answer (score 0):

If server uses self signed certificate then there's nothing you can do.
There are two other ways though, which requires server side certificate changes
and depending on those changes user may or may not have to do some settings in browser

1. Update the server with a Trusted CA issued certificate. 
   This does not require user to do any setting.
   Examples for trusted CAs are GoDaddy, VeriSign etc,.
   You can check the list of Trusted CAs in ***chrome://settings -> HTTPS/SSL -> Manage certificates -> Trusted Root Certificate Authorities***
2. Update the server with a any other CA issued certificate.
   Then provide a way for user to download the certificate and then user has to install/import it in his/her system/PC 
   Once certificates is installed or imported, you can check ***chrome://settings -> HTTPS/SSL -> Manage certificates -> Trusted Root Certificate Authorities*** to confirm that its installed into *"Trusted Root certificates"* folder. Only if certificate is imported into this folder there will be no errors in console for SSL connections.

Of course if you do not want do all this then there is a workaround as you mentioned to tell user to connect to the page in the browser once and accepts the certificate, and then he/she could proceed in the Chrome Apps

Answer (score -3):

http://www.startssl.com/?app=1 provides free SSL certificates. Try having your customers get one of those instead of training your users to accept insecure connections. Or put the insecure connection over http:, which declares the intention to be insecure.